# .NET core - Publish page not showing on VS 2019 (version 16.3.4)

Tags: visual-studio, .net-core, visual-studio-2019, publish-profiles

Since I updated Visual Studio Professional 2019 to latest version (16.3.4), I'm not able to publish my .NET Core console app to a folder anymore (I'm not using online services).

I used to right click on my executable project, click on "**Publish**" menu item, configure my publish profile in a dedicated window and then, of course, publish. This configuration was saved in a XML file in `<myProjectFolder>\Properties\PublishProfiles\`.

Now all I can see when I click on "**Publish**" menu item is the following empty page, from which I can do nothing, neither configure a publish profile nor actually publish.

[image: publish-empty-window]

Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: Try checking your local dotnet core sdk that is used in the pc and the dotnetcore version that the project was build with.If there are differences there can be problems related like this

Comment: @Sathiraumesh I have installed .NET Core SDK for 2.1.401, 2.1.508, 2.1.801, 2.1.802, 2.2.107 and 3.0.100 (last one seems installed yesterday, that is when I updated), and my projects are targeting .NET Core 2.1. I tried also to change their target, but nothing changes.

Comment: actually if you have installed many versions it will auomaticaly choose the latest version and changing the target version in csproj doesnt work.What you have to do is create a global.json file in the root folder of the project and specify the version of dotnetcore that you are going to use that will autmaticaly use the version that is specifed in the global.json file and make sure to install it

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/global-json refer  this